# What tables do I have to create in order to keep track of shipments?

Tags: database, relational-database, normalization, database-normalization

I have `Suppliers`, `Clients` and `Items` tables in my database. I need to keep track of shipments received from suppliers. Each shipment contain many items. I also need to keep track of damaged items from shipments and whether the damaged items are returned or not.

I'm planing to create two extra table called:

- `Shipment` (Shipment_id, supplier_id)
- `Shipment-Tracking` (Shipment_id, items_id, damage, returned)

Is there any better way to create this relationship?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the nature of your items, you might want to include a quantity in your `Shipment-Tracking` table.

You might also add some other information to your `Shipment` table, like the date of the shipment, and so on.

Otherwise, keeping a shipment header and a shipment detail table is a good design.  It is in third normal form, which is a good place to start in a transactional system.